# Cordova: cordova_plugins.js failed to load resource

Tags: android, cordova

I am learning to use cordova and i have been just doing a normal install of android platform in my cordova application, everything worked fine except for some errors i don't intent to fix just yet (which are external resource files loaded from javascript). I just installed [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for working on a push notification support, i believe i have to first register the device on which the notification should be recieved so i ran the app without any other configuration rather than downloading the libraries and putting the `google-services.json` file at the root application folder.

I try to find the commands for pushing but i am unabled to do so and i think it might be because of an error thrown in the console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    /cordova_plugins.js
```

so i have been searching on google and i have found that i don't need to add anything but `cordova.js` as i have already done upon cordova application installation in order to work with cordova features.

I don't know if i have to add something else or if i am missing some code in order to make this plugin work, probably this plugin is not compatible with cordova but phonegap is built over cordova so i don't know.

in case it is necessary, this are the versions i am using:

- Cordova-CLI: 7.1.0
- Google Play Services: 46
- Android support repository: 47
- Android SDK: 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to say that the application running in cordova is done with `angular` and `angular-ui-router`.

After long hours of testing i've found out that the problem is caused by `angular-ui-router`, because i was using `angular-ui-router` i have set a `<base href>` tag in the head tag which is what is making cordova to fail, this is now actually how cordova is intended to work, it is because of how the files are placed. On android the files are placed in `android_asset/www/`, i don't know how the files are placed in other platforms, but when `<base href>` tag is set with a new value then the calls are now trying to be done in a directory where the files are not placed.

The solution in angular is to not set a `<base href>` tag and disable `html5Mode` in the config

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$locationProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", 
    function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        // Set the default url state
        // NOTE: Do not set <base href> tag, this breaks cordova calls
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        // Disable html5 native router mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        ......
    }
]);
```

I've realized this because in chrome device remote inspector i was getting error calls to wrong directories, by looking at the url where the application is running i saw that the calls were not in the proper directory